# Is a “lock of hair” necessarily separate from the rest of someone’s hair?

Tags: meaning, nouns, terminology

When I look up “lock of hair”, and Google, specifically Wikipedia, tells me that it’s separated from the rest of someone’s hair, or just barely on (to quote it directly, “singly on”). Is this necessarily the case? If not, is there another word that means the same sort of large group of hair?

Comment: This is potentially an interesting question, but adding a more specific source than "the internet" could help answerers and other readers. What did you find that claimed "lock of hair" has to be separate from the body?

Comment: This is very subtle and not entirely answerable by reference. By most dictionary references a lock of hair is an object separated from where it grew. Yet 'flowing locks' is very much still attached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why Wikipedia says that.

Traditionally, a *lock of hair* refers to hair that hangs together. The word *lock* has been used this way since Old English ("[lock, n.1,](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109595)" def. 1a in the Oxford English Dictionary). While locks can be cut and collected, and *lock of hair* most commonly specifies such severed clusters of hair, *lock of hair* can also refer to hair still connected to the body, if a single lock is distinct from the rest. That terminology applies whether or not the lock is alone on the head:

> She lay on a couch with her feet up, twining a limp **lock of hair** around her finger and telling Mary about someone named Brady. (Anne Tyler, *[The Clock Winder](https://books.google.com/books?id=yHZBNDXm7EAC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=%22She%20lay%20on%20a%20couch%20with%20her%20feet%20up,%20twining%20a%20limp%20lock%20of%20hair%20around%20her%20finger.%22&source=bl&ots=eN9Xca-wzy&sig=ACfU3U1RKKI8WyEv9UJj57Fl4hQ7dVrTRg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3hNW0xIbyAhWElmoFHeIdDu4Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22She%20lay%20on%20a%20couch%20with%20her%20feet%20up%2C%20twining%20a%20limp%20lock%20of%20hair%20around%20her%20finger.%22&f=false)*)

> Lock of Horus - a **lock of hair** that was left uncut over the right ear of young Egyptian boys. (The rest of the head was shaved.) (Allison Lowery, *[Historical Wig Styling: Ancient Egypt to the 1830s](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Historical_Wig_Styling_Ancient_Egypt_to/FVEdAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lock%20of%20hair%22&pg=PA259&printsec=frontcover)*)

> To add more realism to the hair, a hairstyle feature, such as a ponytail or **lock of hair**, can be animated independent of the rest of the hair. (Rick Parent, *[Computer Animation](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Computer_Animation/ZNZ3XIGeMkgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lock%20of%20hair%22&pg=PA310&printsec=frontcover)*)

Even Wikipedia editors use it:

> A kiss curl describes a **lock of hair** curling onto the face and usually plastered down (Wikipedia, "[Kiss curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_curl)")

> The lovelock was a long **lock of hair**, often plaited (braided) and made to rest on the left shoulder (the heart side) to show devotion to a loved one (Wikipedia, "[Lovelock (hair)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovelock_(hair))")

Comment: True, it is also possible to refer to long hair as 'locks' when it isattached their owner's head. For example "She tossed her auburn locks and stormed out of the room."

Comment: It could also be used to refer to individual pieces of their hair while attached to the rest of their head, like Superman's famous lock of hair on his forehead.

Comment: Also, dreadlocks.